# How do I get Rust to Import log?

Tags: rust

I am migrating a rust project to python and need to understand how a function is working. I know a little about rust but am hardly an expert

I simply want to be able to import `log::warn` into `ab_data.rs` so I can trace the logic.

The project structure is:

```
/src
  lib.rs
  /app
     main.rs
     ...
  /models/
     ab_data.rs
     ...
```

However, it's not simple. I've tried multiple ways to get `ab_data.rs` to import `log`,
and get messages like:

```
  |
9 | use log;
  |     ^^^ no `log` in the root
```

### lib.rs

```
#![feature(plugin, custom_derive)]
#![plugin(rocket_codegen)]

#[macro_use]
extern crate log;

extern crate mysql;

extern crate pwhash;

extern crate chrono;

extern crate rand;

extern crate itertools;

...
```

### app/main.rs

```
#![feature(plugin, custom_derive)]
#![plugin(rocket_codegen)]

#[macro_use]
extern crate log;

extern crate mysql;

extern crate pwhash;

extern crate chrono;

extern crate rand;

extern crate itertools;

...
```

### app/models/ab_data.rs

```
use models::{Date, User};

use mysql;
use mysql::{Pool, Row};

use log;
use log::{warn};

...

impl AbData {
    /// Takes an input struct, and returns an output struct with all fields calculated.
    pub fn calculate(...) -> Self {
        warn!('warn message');
    ...
```

### Cargo.toml

```
...


[[bin]]
...
path = "src/app/main.rs"

...

[dependencies]
...
log = "0.3.8"
mysql = "11.3"
...

[dev-dependencies]
assert_approx_eq = "1.0"

[lib]
path = "src/lib.rs"
```

### Dockerfile

```
RUN rustup install nightly-2018-03-15
RUN rustup default nightly-2018-03-15

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN cargo build --release

...
```

Note that the mysql import works in this module, and I believe I'm following the exact same pattern for log, but it cannot be located.

I'm not a rust programmer, as I mentioned. Any help is appreciated. Let me know if I missed anything important.

Comment: is models have a main ? or cargo.toml have more then one bin ? is lib.rs have a `mod models` ? no [mcve].

Comment: What other errors and warnings do you see?